# Why can't I access properties directly within this object?

Tags: javascript

I have read the documentation for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Why can't we directly access this.prop, but rather we have to write a function just to return this.prop?

```
var test = {
  prop: 42,
  func: function() {
    return this.prop;
  },
  directAccess: this.prop
};

console.log(test.func());
// expected output: 42

console.log(test.directAccess);
// expected output: 42
// actual output: undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about context, at the time you're constructing the object `test` , the `this` context is the parent scope which is creating the object.

When invoking the function, your scope is now that of `test` which at that point does have a property of `prop`.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* directly access `prop`. However, the way to do that is to use `test.prop`.

In JavaScript, `this` is a special variable that is set to the "receiver" of a function call, meaning the object to the left of the dot. When you write

```
test.func()
```

then `test` is the receiver, so `this` points to `test` inside the function.

In the case of `directAccess`, there is no function. The expression `this.prop` is evaluated at the time `test` is *defined*. At this point, `this` is probably the JavaScript default object, which does not have a property called `prop`, so you get undefined.

You might be used to Java, in which `this` inside a class always refers to an instance of the class itself. It doesn't work that way in JavaScript.